# Problemas con cup y flex

Tags: java, eclipse, flex, cup

No me genera el cup los ficheros auxiliares (sym y paraser) , por lo que no se puede generar el traductor.
describo como lo hacemos por si estoy herrando en un paso

1.- desarrollamos el flex con las adaptaciones de cup
2.- desarrollamos el cup 
3.- instanciamos los no terminales en objetos (clases de java) que formaran la gramática (que se cargaran en paralelo en el parser)

```
non terminal ObjCode OP;
OP ::= OPARIT:o  {: RESULT = new Op(o); parser.objCodeInitial=RESULT; :}
;
```

4.- configuramos eclipse de la siguiente manera para que se genere el flex y el cup (como en las imágenes que pongo a continuación)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rii. ¿es necesario hacerlo desde eclipse? ¿no basta con copiar el jar al lugar donde tienes el archivo .lex y ejecutar java -cp jflex-1.6.1.jar -noback rules.flex y hacer lo equivalente para el cup?

Comment: En teoria seria lo mismo y de esta forma no tendria que estar usando la consola de ms2 , es simple limpieza.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente el problema era que al tenerlo sincronizado con git se generaban los ficheros en local y eclipse no los mostraba en el menu porque realmente no estaba actualizados en git (cosa que hay que hacer manualmente)